# Add properties to Vue component programatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Let's say there's a component `<x>` which doesn't know about some property `a` by design but it should be arbitrarily configured and supported by `<x>`.

`const env = { props: { a: Number } }`

`<x :env="env" :a="38">`

Is this ever possible?

Comment: I can't think of a usecase where this could be useful or make sense. Why would you need that ?

Comment: What about passing new props into a special prop like `dynProp`? You could add then your dynamic props via `this.dynProp`. It would also make your code easier to understand and debug imo. Example: `<x :dynProps="{ a: 13 }">` and then `this.dynProps.a` in your component.

Comment: @PascalLamers Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not register the props inside your component `x` like

```
//x.vue
<script>
  export default {
    props : ['a']
  }
</script>
```

then the component wouldn't know anything about props you pass to it. Props you pass to the component, but did not register, will be undefined.

However, it is not a problem to pass a complete object as prop to the component, like

```
/* 
   const obj = {
     a : 1,
     b : 2,
     c : 3
   }
*/

<x :dynprop="obj" />
```

```
<script>
  export default {
    props : ['dynprop'],
    mounted() {
      console.log(dynprop.a);
      
      // 1
    }
  }
</script>
```

Please see **Passing Object as Props** in the official Vue Docs : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object

This will probably your best option since

> Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance.

Comment: Hey, it's not what I'm asking for

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer let me know if this clarifies the problem to you, or if there is anything else to your specifc problem which I missed

Answer (score 0):

Please refer: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects. You can't dynamically add any property Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive

Comment: Even during initialization? I mean that I don't need to add properties once the app is mounted.

Comment: You can create a object as property which you can change(in one the lifecycle hook: mounted). Get whatever you want to change in mounted and set it.